# Cannot get HTTP Headers on Angular Interceptor

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, middleware

I am setting custom headers in nodejs (express) application within the response:

```
res.header('Vme','true')
next()
```

When i get response back to client I can see headers correctly in the browser:
[browserHeaders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaVEy.png)

The problem is that i am not able to access headers inside angular hhtp interceptors:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
this.loaderService.show()
return next.handle(request)
  .pipe(
    map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        const message = event?.body?.message
        if (message?.length) {
          this.toastService.show(event?.body?.message, SeveritiesEmun.Success)
        }
      }
      return event
    }),
    catchError(error => {
      let errorMessage = error?.error || 'Error'
      if (typeof errorMessage === 'object') {
        errorMessage = error?.statusText || 'Error'
      }
      this.toastService.show(errorMessage, SeveritiesEmun.Fail)
      return throwError(errorMessage)
    }),
    finalize(() => {
      this.loaderService.hide()
    })
  )
}
```

In both the error (error) and the successful instance ((event: HttpEvent ))
the "headers" property contains no value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to process the send data like this:

```js
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";


next.handle(req).pipe(
    tap((event: HttpEvent<any>): void => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            // do whatever with event
        }
    })
);
```

Then you can check if your header is applied by doing `event.headers.has("Vme")` and access it by `event.headers.get("Vme")`

Comment: I already checked

response.headers.get('Vme') is 
null
and 
response.headers.has('Vme') is
false

Comment: are you shure that the server send the header? You can check it with the developer network tools of the browser

Comment: I already added a picture of this, see my question below. Inside the tab "network" of the browser i can see the "Vme" header correctly.